# How to link es6 polyfill in a angular 2 application

Tags: android, angular, ecmascript-6, cross-browser, polyfills

I developed a Angular 2 application which doesn't work in Android 4.1.x and more stock browsers.

The only link to Polyfills I have included inside my app is the following:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

I read Angular2 documentation ([here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html#!#core-es6)) and I saw that I have to inculde ES6 Polyfill to make it work on Android devices, but I have no idea how to link it. It is included in `core-js` module, but how to insert it inside the app?

Comment: Were you able to figure out which file for the ployfill to include @B. Ciervo?

Comment: No, but I solved another way... I installed @types/core-js": "^0.9.35" with npm install and changed inside tsconfig.json my target from es6 to es5. Then inserted into "compilerOptions" the following instructions:

     "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types" : [
      "core-js"
    ]    
 and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Also, was there a reason why you decided to use core-js versus other npm modules, like angular2-ie-shims [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-ie9-shims)? I am wondering if the polyfills are any different

Comment: Mmm no, just... I tried and it worked :) did you manage to get it work, too?

Comment: ie-shims for internet explorer. core-js also for android4.1+ . but  PBandJen answer do not work for me. target already was es5 and typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types] i only added "types" : [ "core-js" ] but without success. this angular2 site https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home works fine, but it has hash strategy

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add polyfill code in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42361941/add-polyfill-code-in-angular-2)

Comment: do you still need help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to insert that inside your `<head>`, you can check that it loads by doing a view page source on a computer.

Answer (score 0):

for example inside your bundle
import 'core-js/es6';