# Add polyfill code in Angular 2

Tags: angular, polyfills

How would I add code of a polyfill in a Angular 2 cli-project?

For example, I would like to use the following polyfill from [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes#Polyfill):

```
if (!Array.prototype.includes) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'includes', {
    value: function(searchElement, fromIndex) {
      if (this == null) { throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined'); }
      var o = Object(this);
      var len = o.length >>> 0;
      if (len === 0) { return false; }
      var n = fromIndex | 0;
      var k = Math.max(n >= 0 ? n : len - Math.abs(n), 0);
      while (k < len) {
        if (o[k] === searchElement) { return true; }
        k++;
      }
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

I found another thread where the polyfill is installed via npm ([How to add Web Animations API polyfill to an Angular 2 project created with Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836532/how-to-add-web-animations-api-polyfill-to-an-angular-2-project-created-with-angu)
). But how to do that if there is no npm package?

Comment: is core-js part of your project ?

Answer (score 7):

Note that for your personnal case (using angular 2, [core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) is normally included in most starter packs). so you just need to add this to your `polyfills.ts`:

```
import "core-js/es7";
```

However if you are interested in declaring custom polyfills in typescript, you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37640785/how-do-you-add-polyfills-to-globals-in-typescript-modules). You'll just need to `require("your-custom-polyfill.js")` in `polyfills.ts` then.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will try this approach and give feedback.

Comment: Good answer. It is often included true, but it is worth mentioning how to acquire it if it is not already installed. Also avoid the `@types/core-js` package and use `"lib": ["es2017", "dom"]` in `tsconfig.json` instead. It trips up a lot of people.

Comment: To be specific, for Array.includes you need `import 'core-js/es7/array'`